# PostgreSQL doesn't update itself automatically with the changes in my original shapefile

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I have two shapefiles and I push them into my PostgreSQL via PostGIS Bundle 3 for PostgreSQL and it works fine. But when I delete a feature in the same shapefile imported again as PostGIS in my QGIS the changes doesn't go automatically in my PostgreSQL databank.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have pushed the shapefile into PostGIS, there is no further connection between the shapefile and the PostGIS data set. If you want to update the dataset in PostGIS, you either need to edit it directly from QGIS or you need to update the shapefile and then re-upload it into PostGIS.